# Padding white spaces or zeroes to a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a confusion regarding the usage of the `.format(x)` method. I read from various articles about its usage in different conditions. but I still don't understand the usage

1. of '0' after ':' in the following code. i.e. the part `0>` in curly braces.
2. Are white spaces and zeroes treated the same when applying `format()` to a string?

I am new to python. Hence please help and sorry if it sounds stupid.

`df['tm'] = df['tm'].apply(lambda x:'{0:0>4}'.format(x))`

I am getting proper results. I just need to understand what the format method along with stuff inside the `{}` does in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The righthand 0 is how many places to go to, the lefthand 0 is how many spaces to use. Remember that you don't need the `lambda`, and that `zfill()` is more expressive of what it does.

You can use it like this:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.zfill(15)
```

Comment: Just to be explicit about not needing lambda: `df['tm'] = df['tm'].apply('{0:0>4}'.format)`

Comment: So I realize here is that the '0:0>4' where 0 after ':' is a padding character and limit of spaces total is 4 including the characters that exist + ones that are added.

Comment: Yeah, I usually find something like `'[{:6.6f}]'.format(x,y)` or `f'{x:{y}{z}}.'` easier for rounding